SpringBoot3 and Junit5 @ParameterizedTest
I'm trying to use the convenient Junit 5 @ParameterizedTest in a SpringBoot 3.3.5 project and I get the following log as soon as I add the annotation:
09:17:00.353 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils -- Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [com.xpfibre.daf.CommuneControllerApiTest]: CommuneControllerApiTest does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.
09:17:00.505 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper -- Found @SpringBootConfiguration com.xpfibre.daf.AdafApplication for test class com.xpfibre.daf.CommuneControllerApiTest

Here is my simplied test class:
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles(value = "junit")
public class CommuneControllerApiTest {
    @ParameterizedTest
    @CsvFileSource(resources = "CommunesTestData.csv",numLinesToSkip = 1 )
    void creation (String codeInsee, String nom, String zc, String quadriOi, int testNumero, boolean testResultatAttendu, int testNombreAttendu) throws Exception {
        // Some tests...
    }
}

and the POM relevant sections:
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.5</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
       <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

Can you explain what's the problem please? Is it possible to achieve that? I don't see any mention of the @ParameterizedTest annotation in the SpringBoot 3 documentations but some blog posts talk about it.
If not, what are the possible workarounds?
Thanks

That is just INFO logging showing you what happens internally. Nothing to worry about.
